# Taxonomy block view shows no content

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8.

I am trying to create a block display to show a list of teasers with the taxonomy term of the current node, within a custom region.

The problem is that when I navigate to the page which contains the custom region no content is displayed.

Other blocks display fine when assigned to the custom region so I don't think its anything to do with my templates.

The same view also has a page display (basically the default taxonomy term view) which shows content correctly when i navigate to the node.

I am a relative Drupal newbie so may be missing something obvious here but as far as i can tell the taxonomy view works as a page but not as a region, so either it must be something to do with the block configuration, or Drupal is just not meant to work like this.

Can anybody suggest what might be causing this, or if this is a bad approach explain why?

Answer (score 0):

are u using exposed filters in your view ?
For it to work in blocs , u need to configure in your view

```
    ajax:on
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure but will investigate. Thanks for the suggestion I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: Ah, i just learned what exposed filters are and no i'm not using them. Unfortunately turning on AJAX did not solve my original problem. Still, have an upvote for helping me learn something new.

Comment: what is that block special ? did u do it programmatically ?have u checked under /admin/structure/block/manage/name of your_block the visibility section?